# reactjs trying to work with a carousel by getting data from json

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to get specific url from my json file, based on url request and put it in my carousel's `<p>` tag as background.
For example, if user ask for htt....url/Item1 it will display only the slides from his part of json
So far i have:
`public.js`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Carousel from './carousel'
import Buttons from './buttons'
import Data from './data';
// Main App
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <br />
        {
        Data.map((item, index) => {
        return (              
        <div id={item.index} style={{height: '100%'}}>
            <Carousel loop auto widgets={[Buttons]} className="custom-class">
            { item.slides.map((c, i) => 
            <p style={{backgroundImage:`url(${c.url})`,height: '100%'}}> {c.campanie}</p>                             )
            }
</Carousel>
          </div>
        )})
  }

}}
export default App;
```

and my `Data.js`

```
const Data = [ 
   { 
      "id":0,
      "sala":"Item1",
      "slides":[ {
         "url":"https://picsum.photos/id/1024/1920/1280",
         "campanie":"carduri"
      },
               {
              "url":"https://picsum.photos/id/1022/6000/3376",
              "campanie":"happy-hour"
          }]
   },
   { 
      "id":1,
      "sala":"Item2",
      "slides":[
          {
              "url":"https://picsum.photos/id/1022/6000/3376",
              "campanie":"happy-hour"
          }
      ]
   }
];

export default Data;
```

Comment: Hi Ion, since `Carousel` isn't a public library you should display the carousel code in order to help you figure out what's going on.

Comment: are looking for filter data with user input from json ?

Comment: i have created a codesandbox can you check this one, kindly fork and update if anything is missing and let me know https://codesandbox.io/s/59247881-so-1sh39

Comment: Thanks @DILEEPTHOMAS , I managed to show it the right way.
But it shows both items on the same page.
How can I set the Item1 or Item2 to show based on the route of incoming request?
I forgot to say I am a noobie at react and nodejs.

Comment: @Lhew the module used is re-carousel [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/re-carousel)

Comment: @IonPopescu i didnt find any routes in your code so i think based on this 1022/6000/3376 you need to differentiate the images ? is that what you are looking for

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I am a noobie, i make one step at a time.
I want to implement: if someone Requests URL/Item1 then it will render only pics from that "sala" from json

Comment: @IonPopescu I didnt get much time mostly by today i will check it. Sorry :(

Comment: @IonPopescu Check the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

See the below snippet, you can try like this

you can type as **/url/Item1** , it will load only the specific images.

App.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const Data = [
  {
    id: 0,
    sala: "Item1",
    slides: [
      {
        url: "https://picsum.photos/id/1024/1920/1280",
        campanie: "carduri"
      },
      {
        url: "https://picsum.photos/id/1022/6000/3376",
        campanie: "happy-hour"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    sala: "Item2",
    slides: [
      {
        url: "https://picsum.photos/id/1022/6000/3376",
        campanie: "happy-hour"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const Carousel = props => {
  const { id } = props.match.params;

  const [slides, setSlides] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const filterSlides = Data.find(d => d.sala === id).slides;
    setSlides(filterSlides);
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <>
      {slides.length &&
        slides.map((c, i) => (
          <p
            key={i}
            style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${c.url})`, height: "400px" }}
          >
            {" "}
            {c.campanie}
          </p>
        ))}
    </>
  );
};

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Route path="/url/:id" component={Carousel} />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59247881-so-1sh39)

Comment: I tried your solution but it doesn't show anything. Why did you removed the carousel module and set it as a const.
thanks for help. but i am a noobie, trying to understand all the changes

Comment: Since carousel component code was not there in the question and it was not a public library so.. But the logic remains the same.. Kindly check the codesandbox in the answer

Comment: hello,
I am getting this error:
`  11 |  const [slides, setSlides] = useState([]);
  12 | 
  13 |  useEffect(() => {
> 14 |    const filterSlides = Data.find(d => d.sala === id).slides;
     | ^  15 |    setSlides(filterSlides);
  16 |  }, [id]);
  17 | `

Comment: I am not able to understand the error can you add the issue on codesandbox and share the link or mention the error

Comment: I've uploaded the whole project.
[link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-brook-lrhyr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

I have edited the code, I am trying to pass all values of the `c.url` into an array, which I will pass it into component.

```
const Content = props => {
  const { id } = props.match.params;
  const [sliduri, setSlides] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
        const filterSlides = Data.find(d => d.sala === id).sliduri;
        setSlides(filterSlides);
  }, [id]);
  let slidesArr = [];
  const slidesJsx = sliduri.forEach((c, i) => {
        slidesArr.concat(c.url);
  });
  const slides = slidesArr.concat(slidesJsx);
  console.log(slides);
  return (
        <>
              <Slideshow slides={slides} />
        </>
  );
};
export default Content;
```

so the `slides` var should be an array, but it's not appending values into array